# How to test mail sent from Notification in Laravel

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking

My users can specify if they have Notifications sent to them instantly or to be notified daily of any pending Notifications.

The below works fine with manual testing; now I'd like to write a feature test around this to ensure that an email is sent and not an SMS or nothing.

```php
public function test_instant_notification_is_sent(): void
{
    Mail::fake();

    $this->user = $user = factory(User::class)->create();

    $this->user->update(
        [
            'notification_frequency' => 'instant',
            'notification_method' => 'email',
            'notification_email' => $this->email,
        ]
    );

    $this->user->save();

    $email = ['subject' => 'subject', 'data' => 'data'];
    $sms = 'Test Notification';
    $database = ['some' => 'data'];

    $this->user->notify(new TestNotification($email, $sms, $database));

    Mail::assertSent(MailMessage::class);
}
```

I've written a `TestNotification` to go with it.

```php
class TestNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public function __construct(array $email, string $sms, array $database)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->sms = $sms;
        $this->database = $database;
    }

    public function via($notifiable): array
    {
        return [$notifiable->preferredNotificationMethod()];
    }

    public function toDatabase($notifiable): array
    {
        return $this->database;
    }

    public function toNexmo($notifiable): array
    {
        return (new NexmoMessage)
            ->content($this->sms);
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable): MailMessage
    {
        return (new MailMessage)
            ->greeting($this->email['subject'])
            ->line('Testing Notifications!')
            ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
    }
}
```

My test fails because, as I now see, `MailMessage` is not a `Mailable` and I think `Mail::fake()` and the mail assertions only work with `Mailable`. Incidentally, if I remove `Mail::fake()` the email is sent fine.

How have others managed to test this please without actually sending the email?

Answer (score 7):

When testing Notifications, you'll want to use `Notification::fake()` and make those assertions. See the [Notification Fake](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mocking#notification-fake) of the docs to see what I mean.

```php
    public function test_instant_notification_is_sent(): void
    {
        Notification::fake();

        $this->user = $user = factory(User::class)->create();

        $this->user->update(
            [
                'notification_frequency' => 'instant',
                'notification_method' => 'email',
                'notification_email' => $this->email,
            ]
        );

        $this->user->save();

        $email = ['subject' => 'subject', 'data' => 'data'];
        $sms = 'Test Notification';
        $database = ['some' => 'data'];

        $this->user->notify(new TestNotification($email, $sms, $database));

        Notification::assertSentTo($this->user, TestNotification::class, function ($notification, $channels) {
            // check channels or properties of $notification here
            return in_array('mail', $channels);

            // or maybe check for nexmo:
            return in_array('nexmo', $channels);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Actually I was finding that Notification::Fake wasn't working like this as all the channels get set when it is created so `mail` or `nexmo` or `database` were all true;

Answer (score 4):

The answer turned out to be to check the `via` method as this is only set to one channel (in my case). And I didn't need to check the email was sent at all as @FatBoyXPC pointed out. Final solution:

```
       Notification::fake();

        $this->user->update(
            [
                'notification_frequency' => 'instant',
                'notification_method' => 'email',
                'notification_email' => $this->email,
            ]
        );
        $email = ['subject' => 'Test Subject', 'data' => 'data'];
        $sms = 'Test Notification';
        $database = ['some' => 'data'];

        $notification = new TestNotification($email, $sms, $database);

        $this->user->notify($notification);

        $this->assertEquals(['mail'], $notification->via($this->user));
```

now if I change `email` or `instant` this test fails and passes if `email` and `instant`